# Is `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to define a custom `UITableViewCell` where the `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` is on the left side of a `UILabel`. Should I define it as an image or is there a smarter way?

Many thanks,
  Carlos

Comment: Why would you want it on the left side? The standard way is to simply set accessoryType to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

Comment: Because I also want a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton in the same cell. The tick should be on the left and the button on the right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just an UIView regarding to the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/accessoryView). So just define it as an UIView.

First you have to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell (in this case it's called MyCell). In this class, define the frame of your AccessoryView in the layoutSubviews method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

In your view controller, tell the table to use this class as a cell. Additionaly you have to set the accessoryView to the UIImageView containing you image.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

When the user taps on a cell you can simply change the image of the accessoryView of the table cell.

Comment: How can I set the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark in the UIView?

Comment: Yes, I understand that it can be done with an image. However, I was wondering if I could use the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark instead. If that is not possible, I will use the image as you suggested.

Comment: No, I've realized this a little bit late, sorry. It's not possible to use the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark, because you can not change the frame of it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the **standard**  accessory type for `UITabelViewCell`, Although you could use an image and define your own **custom accessory view** type by assigning `your custom view` (you could add your image here ) in `accessoryView` property of `UITabelViewCell`.

See Documentation fpr [accessoryType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryType)

See Documentation for [accessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible with UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

1. You will have to create a cell in

   ```
   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
   ```
2. add a custom subview, or return a custom cell
3. Make it look like a checkmark or unchecked based on the state of the data.