# How to display a custom UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view that needs a custom UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark. The checkmark displays when a row is selected and disappears when anther row is selected and then appears on the last most selected view. That works fine.

the problem arises when I use this line:

```
 cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ]
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png" ]];
```

to add a custom UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark. After that code the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark remain on all rows and don't disappear when another row is touched.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int index = indexPath.row; id obj = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:index];

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
if (rowNO!=indexPath.row) {
    rowNO=indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ]
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png" ]];

    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPth].accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    lastIndexPth=indexPath;
}
```

Comment: you must create a for cicle for disappear all the other cell

Comment: This link is also useful for you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359043/is-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-an-image

Comment: This link is also useful for you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359043/is-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-an-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A much cleaner and cooler way would be to overwrite UITableViewCell like this:

```
- (void)setAccessoryType:(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)accessoryType
{
    // Check for the checkmark
    if (accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        // Add the image
        self.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]] autorelease];
    }
    // We don't have to modify the accessory
    else
    {
        [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
    }
}
```

If you have done that, you can continue using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` because your class will automatically replace it with an image.

You should only set the style in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // [init subclassed cell here, dont forget to use the table view cache...]

    cell.accessoryType = (rowNO != indexPath.row ? nil : UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);

    return cell;
}
```

And then, you just have to update `rowNO` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to update your data and redraw the cell, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (rowNO != indexPath.row)
    {
        rowNO = indexPath.row;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData]; 

}
```

Also, instead of reloading the whole table with `[self.tableView reloadData]`, you could only reload the two cells that change their style (e.g. checkmark) using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Answer (score 3):

Hm don't know why but i can't add comments so im writing this as answer. The problem with [Blauesocke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301277/blauesocke) answer is that the AccessoryType wil be not set to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark so you can't check the cell AccessoryType. Is there some way to do it right so the cell AccessoryType will be corect type just another image.

I'm using the method like this :

```
- (void)setAccessoryType:(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)newAccessoryType
{
    [super setAccessoryType:newAccessoryType];
    // Check for the checkmark
    switch(newAccessoryType)
    {
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark:
            self.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yorCheckmark.png"]];
            break;
        case UITableViewCellAccessoryNone:
            self.accessoryView = nil;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to check the accessory type?

Comment: Because I'm using it to unchecking or checking the cell. Yes I know there are others possibilities to do that, but I used that in my old code and come request to change the icon. So the answer is that I don't want change the old code :).